# Ayuda Consultas de ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

1. Listar el departamento , el salario total de los departamentos que  la suma de sus salario sea mayor a 20000.

   ```
   SELECT D.DEPARTMENT_NAME,SUM(E.SALARY) FROM DEPARTMENTS DINNER JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON D.DEPARTMENT_ID=E.DEPARTMENT_ID GROUP BY D.DEPARTMENT_NAME;
   ```

   El problema con la primera consulta es como puedo meter el salario total de cada departmento en el WHERE para que este sea mayor a 20000
2. Crear un select que presente el id del puesto, la descripción del puesto, la cantidad de empleados para departamentos que tengan de 4 empleados.

   ```
   SELECT J.JOB_ID,J.JOB_TITLE FROM JOBS J INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON J.JOB_ID=E.JOB_ID;
   ```

   El problema con la segunda consulta es como hago para sacar la cantidad de empleados para los departamentos que tengan mas de 4 empleados
3. Desplegar un select donde desplegué los puestos donde el promedio de los salario sea mayor a 10000.

   ```
   SELECT E.JOB_ID,AVG(E.SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES E GROUP BY JOB_ID;
   ```

   El problema con la tercera consulta es como el proble de la primera consulta como meto el promedio de los salarios en el WHERE y qu este sea mayor 10000

En la consulta 1 y 3 cuando intento hacer `MAX` y `AVG` en el `WHERE` me tira error y lo intente hacer en el `SELECT` pero el `WHERE` no lee los `ALIAS`

Comment: Estás *cenando* (`DINNER`), cuando lo que deberías hacer es una *unión interna* (`INNER JOIN`)  entre las tablas. El problema es que ahí, tu tabla `DEPARTMENT` adquiere el alias `DINNER` (1ª consulta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora mismo no puedo testearlo pero creo que sería algo así:

1. Debes añadir una consulta superior para poder discriminar por la sumatoria de salarios. También aprovecho para corregir el `DINNER` que supongo que se te coló :P:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        D.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
        SUM(E.SALARY) AS SALARY 
    FROM DEPARTMENTS D 
        INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON D.DEPARTMENT_ID=E.DEPARTMENT_ID 
    GROUP BY D.DEPARTMENT_NAME) 
WHERE SALARY > 20000
```

2. Este caso será parecido al anterior, pero a demás debemos añadir una subconsulta más para calcular el total de empleados por departamento.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        J.JOB_ID,
        J.JOB_TITLE,
        (SELECT COUNT(1)
         FROM EMPLOYEES E2
         WHERE E2.DEPARTMENT_ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID) AS EMPLOYEES_BY_DEP
    FROM JOBS J 
        INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON J.JOB_ID=E.JOB_ID)
WHERE EMPLOYEES_BY_DEP > 4
```

3. Más de lo mismo, como el caso 1.